# Requests Module Python text Formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am getting a response that looks like `<a href='Link'>Data<\a>` using the requests module in python (.text), is there I can now save the 'Data' in a variable?

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

yes, what you are looking for is something [like this package: html2text](https://pypi.org/project/html2text/) a package which extract the text from the HTML code you got from your request.

For example:

```py
print(html2text.html2text("<a href='Link'>Data<\a>"))
```

which will print:

> Data

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the text.

Usually it is much more than one a tag. You can list them all with select () and then run through them with a for loop.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
atags = soup.select('a')
for text in atags:
    linktext = text.text
    # Do something with the text
```

But if it's just one a tag, you can run select_one
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
atag = soup.select_one('a')
text  = atag.text
# Do something with the text
```